# What happens to the pole in the susceptibility at a phase transition away from $T_c$?

Tags: phase-transition

At a second order phase transition, a susceptibility such as $\chi = 
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\mu}$ will diverge. In linear response, susceptibilities can be computed as a function of frequency and momentum, e.g. $\chi(\omega,k) \sim \langle \rho \rho \rangle$ with $\rho$ being the (conserved) charge density operator. The $\omega, k \rightarrow 0$ limit should agree with the "thermodynamic" $\chi$, and thus have a pole at the phase transition $T=T_c$.

My questions is, what will happen with this pole in the density-density two-point function when we move away from $T_c$? I was thinking in general it might move into the complex frequency plane, indicating stability or instability depending on which side of $T_c$ you go to. Are there any general statements you can make about its behavior?